# How to convert BSON Timestamp from Mongo changestream to a date?

Tags: mongodb

I am getting started with the Changestream in Mongo. In my current setup a stitch functions inserts the changelog events into a revision collection. However when I read data from the collection, I can't convert the Timestamp fields. I have tried with the following 2 attempts:

**1) A pipeline**

```js
[
    {
        $match: {
            'documentKey._id': _id,
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: -1 },
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            convertedDate: { $toDate: 'clusterTime' },
        },
    },
]
```

But it gives the error: `Error parsing date string 'clusterTime'; 0: passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed 'c'; 6: Double timezone specification 'r'`

**2) The bson Timestamp class**

```js
import { Timestamp } from 'bson';
const asTimestampInstance = new Timestamp(v.clusterTime);
```

But here typescript gives me the error: `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(210, 30): An argument for 'high' was not provided.`

In Altas, the clustertime correctly looks like a timestamp:

[image: Screenshot of data in Atlas]

I hope that I am just missing something simple :)

Comment: It's all about money. You need to add a dollar otherwise the 'clusterTime' will remain just an 11-characters string:  `convertedDate: { $toDate: '$clusterTime' },`

Comment: I added `$clusterTime`, but I now get the error: `"Unsupported conversion from timestamp to date in $convert with no onError value"`

Comment: Ah, indeed, I missed this nuance. Please see my answer.

Comment: Please remove the duplicate question label. The questions are *not* duplicates (they are maybe related, but not more than that). https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/fanpark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) doesn't work with timestamps directly. At least not in v4.0.

The argument should be either a number, a string, or an ObjectId.

You need to convert Timestamp to string first:

```
    $addFields: {
        convertedDate: { $toDate: {$dateToString:{date:"$clusterTime"}} },
    },
```

Comment: We have been using this approach for some time, but have now found out that it actually stripes out ms.

Comment: It stripped nothing. Timestamp's precision is 1 second: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps

Comment: ahh ok - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
2) The bson Timestamp class
```

You should take first 32-bit value from BSON's Timestamp class instance, it means seconds [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then multiply seconds on 1000 and make it milliseconds Epoch time, then call JS Date constructor.

If `v` is document from ChangeStream, v.clusterTime is BSON Timestamp class object. So, you should write:

`const date = new Date(v.clusterTime.getHighBits() * 1000);`

This example worked for me on MongoDB 4.0, ODM Mongoose 5.12, Node.js 12.

Comment: Thanks so much for leaving this here!