# How to convert BSON Timestamp from Mongo changestream to a date in javascript?

Tags: mongodb

I already have [a SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490045/how-to-convert-bson-timestamp-from-mongo-changestream-to-a-date) on how to convert BSON Timestamp in a MongoDB aggregation, but now I have a situation where I would like to convert in node.js.

So just to repeat. My goal is to convert a "Timestamp" datatype to a javascript date, without doing it in an aggregation - is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the BSON library you are using provides `Timestamp` type, you can use its `getTime` method to return the seconds, and create a date from that:

```
Date(object.clusterTime.getTime())
```

If you don't have that function available, the timestamp is a 64-bit value where the high 32-bits are the seconds since epoch, and the low 32-bits are a counter.

Bitshift the value 32 bits right or divide by 2^32 to get the seconds:

```
Date(object.clusterTime/Math.pow(2,32))
```